# Attempting to Drawing A Dropshadow-Like Gradient on the Edge of a Control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, system.drawing

I'm trying to create a function that will generate a dropshadow-like gradient on any given edge of a control. I'm not extremely familiar with `System.Drawing`, but have used it once before, and used that experience to try to make this. I am essentially drawing a gradient, one-pixel line by one-pixel line (through a for loop that uses a value called `length` to determine the number of lines), that changes based on the `alpha` value of a `pen` I'm using.

The issue is definitely either that I'm incorrectly calculating how to get the `alpha` value for the next line, or that I'm using `System.Drawing` incorrectly. I think it may be the latter; I can't figure out how to get the `bitmap` I'm generating to display, whether by using `Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics()` or by setting the `graphics` from the `bitmap`.

I'm not sure how I would break up the code for this question, but it's a relatively short function anyhow. See the documentation for more details on how the function is supposed to work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a simple drop shadow at any rectangular angle along the edge of a control of choice.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="startAlpha">The starting alpha (transparency) value of the gradient of the shadow.</param>
/// <param name="fourthsRotationDirection">The rotation (in 90 degree values) of the shadow.</param>
/// <param name="control">The control to be given a shadow.</param>
/// <param name="length">The length or depth of the shadow.</param>
/// <param name="clearShadow">Determines whether or not the function should clear all graphics to rid of any preexisting shadows, mostly for regeneration purposes.</param>
void DropShadowGenerator(int startAlpha, FourthsRotationDirection fourthsRotationDirection, Control control, int length, bool clearShadow)
{
    PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
    image.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    image.Size = this.Size;
    this.Controls.Add(image);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    Pen pen = (fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.Zero || fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.OneEighty) ? new Pen(Color.FromArgb(startAlpha), control.Height) : new Pen(Color.FromArgb(startAlpha), control.Width);
    Point startPoint = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();
    float shadowFactor = 255 / length;
    float currentAlpha = startAlpha;

    if (clearShadow)
    {
        graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    }

    if (fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.Zero)
    {
        startPoint = new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width, control.Location.Y);
        endPoint = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y + control.Height);
    }
    else if (fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.OneEighty)
    {
        startPoint = new Point(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y);
        endPoint = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y + control.Height);
    }
    else if (fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.Ninety)
    {
        startPoint = new Point(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y);
        endPoint = new Point(startPoint.X + control.Width, startPoint.Y);
    }
    else if (fourthsRotationDirection == FourthsRotationDirection.TwoSeventy)
    {
        startPoint = new Point(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y + control.Height);
        endPoint = new Point(startPoint.X + control.Width, startPoint.Y);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {            
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, endPoint);

        currentAlpha = currentAlpha - shadowFactor;
        pen.Color = Color.FromArgb((int)currentAlpha, Color.Black);

        switch (fourthsRotationDirection)
        {
            case FourthsRotationDirection.Zero:
                startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X++, startPoint.Y);
                endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X++, endPoint.Y);
                break;

            case FourthsRotationDirection.OneEighty:
                startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X--, startPoint.Y);
                endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X--, endPoint.Y);
                break;

            case FourthsRotationDirection.Ninety:
                startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y--);
                endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X, endPoint.Y--);
                break;

            case FourthsRotationDirection.TwoSeventy:
                startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y++);
                endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X, endPoint.Y++);
                break;
        }
    }

    image.Image = bmp;
}
```

How can I get this to display on my form? As mentioned before, am I simply using System.Drawing incorrectly, or is my gradient generation itself incorrect?

Comment: Suggestion: Stop trying to reinvent the wheel. It's already been invented. Use WPF and you can get this done in 2 lines of XAML as opposed to fighting winforms incapabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the way you calculate the new coordinates:

```
startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X++, startPoint.Y);
endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X++, endPoint.Y);
```

That does not actually change the coordinates, because you assign the value first and then you increase it. 
Try:

```
startPoint = new Point(++startPoint.X, startPoint.Y);
endPoint = new Point(++endPoint.X, endPoint.Y);
```

or, which I find more readable:

```
startPoint = new Point(startPoint.X+1, startPoint.Y);
endPoint = new Point(endPoint.X+1, endPoint.Y);
```

Or without creating a new Point, then you can do what you did:

```
startPoint.X++;
endPoint.X++;
```